# Account merge request

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, user-accounts

Please merge my old Electronics.StackExchange account with my account here.

Comment: First, it's most helpful if you can link to both accounts, or at least provide your ID number.  However, I'm curious where the Electronics.SE (version 1.0) questions, answers, and users went. It looks like everything was jettisoned.

Comment: More info: All of the links that I found to EE.SE 1.0 questions and answers (here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266/ linked here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/4310#4310, here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/147/ linked here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1196, and here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111/117#117 linked here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/1267#1267) are broken.  They resolve to the wrong page, but they resolve.  It's interesting.  Adding the "bug" tag for this reason.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, since I can't get to the old site, I can't come up with ID numbers.

Comment: Understood.  I just didn't want others with similar problems, but knowing both accounts, to copy this question and fail to include their user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er.. what?

Can you provide links to your other account? Or questions and answers provided under it? I only see one "Lance Roberts" at

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/1395

edit: per https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/4310#4310

The original electronics.stackexchange.com *was not Chiphacker*, it was another site on electronics that didn't have very many questions so we didn't migrate it.

Comment: The other account was on the Electronics SE 1.0, which is no longer accessible, so I can't link to it, but I had participated.  I don't even see that my questions have been migrated.  Note reemrevnivek's comments to the question.

Comment: @lance see my updated response; two different sites, one was migrated, the other was not.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess I'm out in the cold, with no questions and not even the measly rep I had.